# How to implement floating chat heads in flutter?

Tags: flutter

An application I'm working on needs something similar to messenger's floating chat heads. And I want to develop my app using Flutter. Can we do that?

[[image: illustration]]

Comment: Can you be more specific, i.e. show the design you want to achieve and where in your existing code you want to implement it?

Comment: I've added an image. It may be a duplicate but I need a solution. There's no solution there

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that at the moment you will need to implement overlays in native android. [Here is an example](https://medium.com/exploring-code/create-chat-heads-like-facebook-messenger-32f7f1a62064) how to approach it. You can connect them with flutter via [platform-channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/).

You can still write the app in flutter for iOS and Android, the only thing is that you will logically need to separate platform-specific code.

Comment: So if I implement the platform specific code for Android, will my app work for iOS too?

Comment: It will work for iOS as well. You would run Android code only if the Platform is Android. You can extract platform specific code into separate logic. Make it modular, so that it doesnt affect the app behind. When you run the app on iOS you just dont invoke the process for android. That is how plugins work.

Comment: I managed to create a plugin for this, is the very start, if could open the question to accept the new answear

https://pub.dev/packages/bubble_overlay

Comment: @Kohls A very good package. How can we make the floated window draggable. Could you please provide this feature.

Comment: @santanubera it is draggable, I provided a demo on Google Play

Comment: Hi @Kohls, your package is DISCONTINUED now, Can we know why is that? and what is the alternative of that?