# How to render a component on top of device screen using react native or flutter?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flutter

I'm working on an app and I want a component to always be on top of the screen and the user can access the app feature using that button.is it possible to implement the button with react-native or flutter?

[component example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZUQ3.jpg)

Comment: is the floating action button not enough? 
you can implement it using a stack widget

Comment: no, I want it to be shown on top of other apps not my own.

Comment: in that case, follow this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630133/how-to-implement-floating-chat-heads-in-flutter