# Floating button that overlaps in all applications

Tags: flutter, dart, button, overlay, floating

I am learning flutter, and I found myself with the task of creating a floating button, that by minimizing the application the button is visible and overlaps any application, is it possible to create this functionality in flutter?

Comment: I don't sure what you want, but if you want achieve sth like `messenger bubbles`, you can find answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630133/how-to-implement-floating-chat-heads-in-flutter)

Comment: Thank you very much, you have helped me get closer to an answer, if I add a functional button on an android platform, will this button work the same on ios?

Comment: if you are using  platform-channels to define some function, you need to do it both android and IOS platform. In your case, I afraid It is only work on android platform since I do not find any support in IOS platform.

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe looking for something like this

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_overlay_window

This only seems to support Android devices.
There are quite a few similar ones there but all of them seems to support Android only.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Scaffold and there's a parameter called `floatingActionButton`. There you can add a button and it definitely won't overlay anything. You should also search for `SafeArea` and `Listview`/`SingleChildScrollView`. These are great widgets for avoid overlays. Flutter has a great documentation so you can always look up a widget in google and there will be always something.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, however, I already have all the functionality of the button created within the application, what I really want is that this button continues to work even with the application minimized, as to give you an example, something like the messenger bubbles

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, but I don't know the answer for that but I'm not sure if Flutter is even flexible enough for this kind of usage. I'd guess not but there are always a lot of new feature so... Good luck for finding the answer, I hope somebody can help :)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to try to resolve this issue! : D

Comment: Any progress on this? I want to do the same thing